# Back button click event of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to capture the back-button event of browser

is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

There is no *back button* event, but you can detect history changing with [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_popstate_event) event.